# How to show popup box even if user change url to another page?

Tags: php, jquery, popup

I make a popup dialog with jquery ui and ask a few question to user when they use my site. User must answer that question. If not, user can't access anything on my site.

But the problem is, when users seen popup box and not answer that question then change url to special link or some link of my site in address bar, they don't need to answer that question and can access the other page.

I don't want to access users before they are not answer question. So, I want to show my popup box even if the user change url to another page.

I made this popup question in `popup.php` page. Here is my code.

```
<?php
....//another code
....//check user session id and show dialog
...
...
echo "<div id='dialog'>";
    echo "Question"."<br/>";
    //select random answer for related question from database
    $sql = "...get answer for question...";
    $query = .....;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        $a_id = $row['id'];
        $answer = $row['name'];
        echo "<input type='radio' value=\"$a_id\" name='answer' class='answer'>$answer <br/>";
    }
echo "</div>";
.....
.....
<scirpt>
$("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen:true,
    width: 500,
    modal: true,
    resizable:false,
    draggable:true,
    position: {my: 'center', at: 'center', of: window, collision:'fit'},
    open: function (event, ui) {
        $('.ui-dialog').css('z-index',1100);
        $('.ui-widget-overlay').css('z-index',1000);
        $("#btn_submit").button("disable");
    },
    create: function(event, ui) {
        $("body").css({ overflow: 'hidden' });
    },
    buttons: {
        Submit: {
            text : "Submit",
            id : "btn_submit",
            click:function() {
                ......//another code
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    dataType:'json',
                    url:'check_question.php',//this is check for user answer is correct or not
                    data:{..//some data....},
                    success: function(data){
                                alert("success");
                            },
                    error: function () {
                            alert("Error");
                            }
                    }); 
                } 
            }      
        }
    }); 
</scirpt>
?>
```

And I add this file to my home page(index.php) with `include("popup.php")`.

Normally, I need to check user is answer or not in every page of my site.
But, its a problem for me because we have a lot of pages.

And I want to coding for checking user changing url and show popup in `popup.php` file.

So, Is there any way to show my popup box even if user changed the url?

Comment: show us what have you done .

Comment: @Drudge I already add what I did, but the main point I want to know is how can I check user is change or not url to another page before they answer anything and if they changed url, I want to show popup box on that page. I want to make all this procedure in `popup.php`. Is it possible?

Comment: how do you know if user gives answer ??

Comment: @Drudge Sorry, I left that part because code is very long. At first, when user login, I check session id and if user not answer anything I'll show popup for that user. If user answer(correct or incorrect is not important), I will show popup box again for that user, answer is correct or not. After that, user can access anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I take current page like this `$current_page="http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";`.

And add current page to session and check page form session is same or not, when user request `popup.php`.

I hope it helps for someone.